# Sorting by Descending QuestionPercentage variable

Tags: sas

Hi I am trying to make two tables that are sorted I believe with proc means or at least the first one I was able to make with proc means. I created the first table with this code.

```
  proc means data=onetable mean noprint;
  var Score;
  class Form QuestionNumber;
  ways 2;
  output out=table (drop=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) mean=QuestionPercentage;
  run;
  title "Section B: Question Analysis "
  "Sorted by Exam Form and Question Number";
  proc print data=table noobs;
  format QuestionPercentage percent8.1;
  run;
```

Which produces a table that looks like this

| Form | QuestionNumber | QuestionPercentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 16.0% |
| A | 2 | 76.0% |
| A | 3 | 42.0% |

Now I am trying to make the second table that looks like this

| Form | QuestionNumber | QuestionPercentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 9 | 100.0% |
| A | 39 | 100.0% |
| A | 101 | 100.0% |

which I think should be made with proc means but I get the error QuestionPercentage not found. I think it might have to do with the mean=QuestionPercentage or what table I am using. Here is my code for the second table.

```
  proc means data=onetable mean;
  var Score;
  class QuestionPercentage;
  ways 2;
  output out=table1 (drop=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) mean=QuestionPercentage;
  run;
  title "Section B: Question Analysis "
 "Sorted by Question Percentage";
proc print data=table1 noobs;
by descending QuestionPercentage;
format QuestionPercentage percent8.1;
run;
```

Any ideas for how to fix this error and get the table I need?

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem

```
   proc sort data=table1 out=sortedtable;
   by descending QuestionPercentage;
   run;
   proc print data=sortedtable noobs;
   format QuestionPercentage percent8.1;
   var QuestionPercentage Form QuestionNumber;
   run;
```